# DDD using repository in entity for validation before update

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories, aggregateroot

Let's say I wan't to update a nickName of Person entity, with rule that this nickName is used by up to 5 other Persons. How should I do it?

Should I do validation in domain service, before calling an update?

Or is it better to pass a personRepository into PersonEntity.update(...) method, and do the search and validation inside entity update method?

---

Additional clarification:

@plalx idea of creating additional entity for executing this rule is clever.

When I am reading about DDD I often read that passing a repository into entity is not recomended (if not evil). That's why I try to find an example where we need a repository or some other service in entity). I actually don't know if only passing repository is bad and service is ok, or passing a service into entity is similarily discouraged.

Let's assume that this rule is not so hard and important business rule, and we can have multiple similar rules (so many, that creating an additional entity for each rule for each attribute we want to validate is a little bit overengineered). Lets assume we can allow 6 or 7 same nicknames in case of concurrent update (we only want to limit them to reasonably small number) and check of

```
personRepository.usageOfNickname(this/person.nickname) < 5
```

is sufficient. In such a case, which design is better from DDD point of view?

- passing personRepository into Person Entity

  `class Person {
  ...
      boolean changeNickname(newNickname, nicknameUsageService) {
          if (personRepository.usageOfNickname(this.nickname) < 5) {
              this.nickname = newNickname;
              return true;
          } else {
              return false; //or throw 
          }
      } 
  }`

  this seems most obvious and straighforwad to me, benefit is that logic is enclosed in Entity, but what bothers me is this wretched passing of repository into entity and this sense that this is discouraged by Evans
- instead of passing personRepository into Person Entity passing personService into Person Entity (similar as in example of @plalx) - is passing a service into Entity anyhow better than a repository?
- doing validation in service similar as in @plalx sample `changePersonNickname(personId, newNickname){...}` but in @plalx's sample using a service seems justified, as it operates on two Entities, here we have only one Entity and I'm afraid if putting this logic in service instead of in Entity it concerns wouldn't be going towards Anemic Domain Model and leaving DDD.

Comment: The downside of having injected services is that it makes testing more tedious (more mocks/stubs needed). The reason you wouldn't pass an entire repository is to respect the Interface Segregation Principle (ISP); favor task-specific interfaces (e.g. `NicknameUsageProvider` which can be implemented by the repository class). Finally, what you can do as well is fetch the data in the application service and pass it to the AR's method. `nicknameUsage = …; person.changeNickname(newNickname, nicknameUsage)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or is it better to pass a personRepository into
>   PersonEntity.update(...) method, and do the search and validation
>   inside entity update method?

That wouldn't prevent the rule from being violated through concurrency though, since as soon as you checked `personRepo.usageCountOfNickname(nickname) <= 5` it could have changed right after.

If you want strong consistency, you could introduce a `NicknameUsage` aggregate root to enforce that policy. You would be modifying more than 1 AR in a transaction, but that's probably not a big deal since it's very unlikely that there will be a lot of contention on the same nicknames anyway, right?

E.g.

```
changePersonNickname(personId, newNickname) {
    transaction {
        person = personRepository.personOfId(personId);

        currentNicknameUsage = nicknameUsageRepository.usageOfNickname(person.nickname);
        currentNicknameUsage.release();

        newNicknameUsage = nicknameUsageRepository.usageOfNickname(newNickname); 
        nicknameUsage.reserve(); //throws if 6 already

        person.changeNickname(newNickname);
    }
}
```

You could as well encapsulate the nickname's usage management logic in a domain service which is then injected in the AR's `changeNickname` operation.

E.g.

```
class Person {
    ...
    void changeNickname(newNickname, nicknameUsageService) {
        nicknameUsageService.reserveAndRelease(newNickname, this.nickname);
        this.nickname = newNickname;
    } 
}
```

If you wish to eliminate all risks of `NicknameUsage` getting out of sync with `User-Nickname` relationship you can design so that `NicknameUsage` is the sole entity tracking the relationship between users and their nicknames (nickname not part of `User` AR at all).

Finally, I dont have much experience with eventual consistency and hopefully someone else will shed some light on what would be the right approach, but if you dont want to modify many ARs per transaction then I think there's a few strategies you could use.

For instance, you can let > 6 persons use the same nickname, but then have a process that detects violations and tag such persons with a nickname policy violation, where they have a grace period to change their nickname or else it will be set to something else automatically (or any other compensating action). Note that you would still have a check in place using a domain service to limit the number of violations though.

If you want to prevent violations, you could also use some kind of saga, where the new nickname is first reserved, then the old one is released and finally the person's nickname is changed. There will be a short period of time where a person would actually have 2 nicknames under reservation, but there would never be a time where nicknames are used more than 6 times.

Comment: Thx for great response. I have added more clarification into my question. Please have a look. Saga and process detecting violations are also nice idea, but I would like to know, if it's sufficient we can pass a repository into entity, or we should avoid it by all means, even by adding additional NicknameUsage entity,